# How to setup main page to show even when you just type the default folder containing it

Tags: php, html

For example this is what I type `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/At/html/` in the URL. I want the `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/At/html/pages-login.php` to appear. How Can I do this?

Comment: Rename `pages-login.html` to `index.html`

Comment: server first checks index.html page from folder,your first page should be index.html,so change your `pages-login.php` to `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default page is `index.html` . But you can use any file as default by using `.htaccess` file.

Create an .htaccess file on `C:/xampp/htdocs/At/html/` and put the code,

```
DirectoryIndex pages-login.php
```

Now the default loading page will be `pages-login.php`

Answer (score 0):

The first file the server tries to load is `index.html` / `index.php` so on.

So simply renaming your file to `index.html` should solve that issue.

Alternatively you can keep a `index.html` which will redirect you to `pages-login.html` or by `.htaccess` file you can manage that behaviour.